# Why does the way a cell is reference make a difference

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

```
    ReDim arOUTPUT(NBJOIN, 2)
    For Counter1 = 1 To NBJOIN
        For Counter2 = 1 To 2
            arOUTPUT(Counter1, Counter2) = COORD(Counter1, Counter2)
        Next Counter2
    Next Counter1
```

This line of code produces an error

```
.Range(.Cells(9,2)).Resize(NBJOIN, 2) = arOUTPUT
```

[image]

This version of the code does not

```
.Range("B9").Resize(NBJOIN, 2) = arOUTPUT
```

I want to be able to use row and column numbering like in the first line of code.  Where did I go wrong?  why is there a difference `.cells(1,1)` and `"A1"`

Comment: What is your `With`-statement?

Comment: essentially `With Thisworkbook.Worksheets("OUTPUT")`

Comment: Can it be that you mixed up what works and what not? `.Range(.Cells(9,2))` is an invalid syntax (and the error that you get has nothing to do with writing data into it). When you pass only one parameter to `Range`, it must be an range address (like `B9`). When you pass 2 parameter, the define start and end cell and you can use the `.Cells` syntax to specify those 2 cells. But in your case, simply use `.Cells(9,2).Resize(NBJOIN, 2) = arOUTPUT`

Comment: @FunThomas if you make that an answer I will go ahead and accept it.  I though I might have had to do `.Range(.Cells(9,2),Cells(9,2)).Resize`...

Comment: `Cells(9, 2)` *is* a Range, so of course you can resize it. BTW: You likely want to define your array like this: ` ReDim arOUTPUT(1 to NBJOIN, 1 to 2)`, else it will start with index 0 (except if you use `Option Base 1`

Comment: I have `Option BASE 1` set

Comment: From documentation: *Represents a cell, a row, a column, a selection of cells containing one or more contiguous blocks of cells, or a 3D range.* It's why you'll see people use `lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` for example which uses the same things a range can. `.Offset()` of course also falls under this inclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not writing data from an array into a range. You simply cannot define a range like this: `.Range(.Cells(9,2))`.

`Range` can be used with one or with two parameters:
When using it with one parameter, you need to specify the range address, eg
`Range("B9")` or `Range("A1:C3")` or `Range("F:H")`

When using it with two parameters, you can specify start and end Range (usually start and end cell) of the range:
`Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 5))` or `Range(Range("A1"), Cells(4, 5))` or the like.

Note that `Cells` defines a single cell (by row and column), but a single cell is also a Range.

In your case, you can simply use

```
.Cells(9,2).Resize(NBJOIN, 2) = arOUTPUT
```

Hint: In such cases, it often helps to define a intermediate variable to split statements.

```
Dim destRange As Range 
Set destRange = .Range("B9")          ' OK
Set destRange = .Cells(9, 2)          ' OK
Set destRange = .Range(.Cells(9, 2))  ' Error 1004
Set destRange = destRange.Resize(NBJOIN, 2)  ' OK
destRange.Value = arOUTPUT
```

P.S.: For the array definition: Even if you have `Option Base 1` set, I would strongly recommend that you always define lower and upper bounds of all dimensions. It happens too often that you (or someone else like me in this case) copies code and - *surprise* - it fails because something that was true in one case is no longer true in the other.