# How to use the .range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a portion of the code I am using and is the one causing the error through debug, I am xsure I input the .Range value wrongly. Does anyone know how to use it? I know supposedly the .Range should be `ws1.Range("E2:E4")`. But how do I make it so that I can make it use the rng1 as a data. Mainly because the rng1 value would change and I would like to use it. Hopefully I explained the question properly.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim chart20 As ChartObject

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Summary")
Set rng1 = ws1.Range("E2")
Set chart20 = ws4.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=5, Left:=410, Width:=400, Height:=250)

With chart20.Chart
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ws1.Range("rng1.Offset(-6, 18).Address:rng1.Offset(-6, 19).Address")
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ws1.Range("E2:F2")
End With
```

Comment: In your case, it'd be something like `ws1.Range(rng1.Offset(-6,18).Address & ":" & rng1.Offset(-6,19).Address)`, also check out [FunThomas' answer from just a bit ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78068180/why-does-the-way-a-cell-is-reference-make-a-difference/78068383#78068383). However in your case, you could just use `rng1.Offset(-6,18).Resize(,2)` which is the same.